# Passing Excel type Variable into PowerShell Function

Tags: excel, function, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm basically trying to create a Power Shell function which takes in a variable set to an excel worksheet and returns the last used row and column.

I know the code works outside of a function. Here's what it looks like in my function.

```
Function FindRange ([string] $path)
{
 $mainRng = $path.UsedRange.Cells 
 $ColCount = $mainRng.Columns.Count 
 $RowCount = $mainRng.Rows.Count  
 $xRow = $RowCount
 $xCol = $ColCount
 Write-Host "function DEBUG xrow:" $xRow
 Write-Host "function DEBUG xcol: " $xCol
 Write-Host "function path:" $path
}
FindRange $BTWSRawSheets
```

$BTWSRawSheets is:

```
 $BTWSRawSheets = $wbBTWS.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "Export Worksheet"}
```

The output of Write-Host "function path:" $path is

```
 function path: System.__ComObject
```

Is anyone able to help me figure out how to pass the excel worksheet in as the parameter? I've spent a few hours researching and trying but have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up whether it's a spreadsheet filename (a text string, $path is a reasonable name for it) or whether it's a live COM object of a running Excel instance, connected to a worksheet. Given the way you use $path.UsedRange directly, and from the output message, I guess it's supposed to be the latter one - so the way you are casting the parameter to a `[string]` is breaking it.

Try removing the [string] type:

```
Function FindRange ($path)
{
...
```